# How can convert SQL to lambda or LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, lambda

How can I convert below SQL to lambda or LINQ?

```sql
with cte
as (select * from test1
    union all
    select * from test2)

select * from cte
union all 
select sum(columnA),sum(columnB),sum(columnC) from cte
```

Comment: Which LINQ are you using? LINQ to Objects, to SQL, to EF 6 / EF Core 2.0 / EF Core 2.1 / EF Core 3.x ?

Answer (score 0):

In Linq `UNION ALL` is `.Concat()`, so:

```cs
var cte = test1.Concat(test2);
var sums = new MyModel
  {
     columnA = cte.Sum(c => c.columnA),
     columnB = cte.Sum(c => c.columnB),
     columnC = cte.Sum(c => c.columnC),
  }

return cte.Concat(IEnumerable.Repeat(sums, 1));
```

You must remember that `test1` and `test2` must be type `MyModel` and `MyModel` contains only `columnA`, `columnB` and `columnC`.

Comment: Could you be more specyfic: what is doesn't work? What is your error message or unexpected result?

Answer (score 0):

I put two tables together in one datagridvie but in the last row of datagridview I need the total for both tables in the country, I can do one row in total for one table and another row for the other table I also don't need it, like I can only have one line with the total of both tables.

> 

DataContex db = new DataContex();

var query = (
               from v1 in db.View1
               where shf.Date >= dpDate.Value && shf.Date <= dpDate1.Value
               select new 
               {
                    
                   v1.Name,
                   v1.Date,
                   v1.Quality,
                   v1.Rat,
                   v1.Total                                     
                   
               }
           ).Concat
           (
               from v2 in db.View2
               where f.Date >= dpDate.Value && f.Date <= dpDate1.Value
               
               select new
               {

                   v2.Name,
                   v2.Date,
                   v2.Quality,
                   v2.Rat,
                   v2.Total
               }
           ).Concat

      (from View2 in

           (from v2 in db.View2
            where v2.Date >= dpDate.Value && sh.Date <= dpDate1.Value
            select new
            {
                   v2.Name,
                   v2.Date,
                   v2.Quality,
                   v2.Rate,
                   v2.Total
            })
       group v2 by new { v2.NRFA } into g
       select new
       {
           Name = "Total:",
           Date = dpDate1.Value,
           Quality = (decimal?)g.Sum(p => p.Quality),
           Rate = (decimal?)g.Sum(p => p.Rate),
           Total = (decimal?)g.Sum(p => p.Total)
       }
           );

> Blockquote